# Traveling to Italy as US permanent resident and no passport from country or origin

Tags: visas

I came to the US 50 + years ago from Cuba. I have been a US permanent resident for 50 years and no longer have a Cuban passport. How can I travel to Italy?

Comment: How did you come to the US and become a permanent resident? This is important information as it will indicate what travel documents may be available to you.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to become a US citizen, which you are almost certainly eligible for.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold for now.